# Htop process viewer - set column width

Tags: linux, htop

I try to enlarge the `htop` column's width. I've found a solution [here](https://github.com/hishamhm/htop/issues/231), but it seems very specific and also too difficult. Is there any simpler way to make all the characters in a column visible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got here from this question: https://serverfault.com/questions/740496/htop-cgroup-column-widen/740533?noredirect=1#comment926040_740533 which is a duplicate of yours.

In short, in current versions the column width is fixed. You can ask for this enhancement to the devs or implement it yourself :-)

You can use ps to find the processes in control groups you're interested in.

Comment: I use latest version, which is 1.0.3.